# CSS3 background-position in percentage not working at all

Tags: css, css-animations

So I'm coding a parallax effect in CSS3 with 3 layers for a page header. My style sheet is the following:

```
#graphic-layer { /* overall properties for graphic layers */
    position: absolute;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#graphic-layer.header { /* header-class */
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-animation-name: header;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
#graphic-layer.header:nth-of-type(1) {  /* parallax layer 1 */
    background-image: url('images/header-background.jpg');
    -webkit-animation-duration: 100s;
}
#graphic-layer.header:nth-of-type(2) {  /* parallax layer 2 */
    background-image: url('images/header-middle.png');
    -webkit-animation-duration: 80s;
}
#graphic-layer.header:nth-of-type(3) { /* parallax layer 3 */
    background-image: url('images/header-foreground.png');
    -webkit-animation-duration: 60s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes header {  /* keyframes */
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100% 0; /* <- PROBLEM HERE */
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** HTML, simply three instances of graphic-layer with class header:

```
<div id="graphic-layer" class="header"></div>
<div id="graphic-layer" class="header"></div>
<div id="graphic-layer" class="header"></div>
```

So far, so good. Note, my header is 100% width of the screen. This works perfectly fine if I set the background position at keyframe 100% to `background-position: 1920px 0;` (my screen/window width) but as soon as the resolution of the window changes, this obviously won't work anymore. If I set the value lower, to 500px, for example, the picture moves 500 pixels and jumps back to the start but I want it to continously move without "jumping".

So I need a solution to make the image move exactly 100% of the width of the header and then restart the animation. But when I set the background position at keyframe 100% to `background-position: 100% 0;` it doesn't move at all.

What is the problem here? Why are the percentage values not working?

**EDIT:**

Found the answer myself!

It was just a stupid error in reasoning. `#graphic-layer.header` doesn't have to be 100% of the header but 100% of the image, which is a static value (in this case 1920px). So if I set the width to 3480px (1920x2) and then change the keyframes to the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes header {  /* keyframes */
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        left: -1920px; /* <- Image size */
    }
}
```

...then the header class moves 1920px to the left and starts over again and because of the doubled width of the class it seems like it is an endless image. No need for relative percentage values!

Comment: Maybe add a fiddle and/or basic html code? Your code doesn't seem to be correct `#graphic-layer` has 3 instances? This id is on the element `header` or are you missing the `.` to indicate a class?

Comment: You can use an `id` only once per page. You can use `graphic-layer1`, `graphic-layer2` and `graphic-layer3`

Comment: Sorry, this is a very dumb and bad habit from early times when I began learning CSS. Thanks for the hint, fixed my code.